# How to rewrite this JS to support trim()

Tags: javascript

How can I rewrite the following to do the same thing but to also support trim() for IE.

```
var isAnonymous = settings.requester_name == null || settings.requester_name.trim() == "";
```

Comment: IE 9+ supports `trim()`. Are you testing this on a an earlier version than that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var isAnonymous = !settings.requester_name || !settings.requester_name.trim();
```

And you can use this polyfill:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+|[\s\xA0]+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below, if `trim()` is not supported

```
function myTrim(x) {
   return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}

function myFunction() {
   var str = myTrim("        Hello World!        ");
   alert(str);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jvf4xp5v/)

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript an empty string is a falsy value, so is null or undefined, given that the following should work

`var isAnonymous = !settings.requester_name || !settings.requester_name.trim()`

The second part of the expression converts the empty string into a boolean, which evaluates false if empty.

What version of IE are you using?  Trim has been supported for a while...

If you are writing for older than ie9 you can add a polyfill for trim

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
   String.prototype.trim = function () {
     return this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+|[\s\xA0]+$/g, '');
   };
}
```

FFR: Mozilla developer network is a great source for Javascript app docs, and they include polyfill implementations you can use for old browser support.

Heres the docs for trim (the polyfill may look familiar) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: Did you even read the question? According to your edit, you didn't. He's trying to get support for IE < 9, the only IE versions that don't natively support it.

Comment: Calm down homeboy, it doesn't say ie9 anywhere I  the question.

Comment: Your original answer had nothing to do with his question... on top of that, you put the exact same code as CD's answer into yours, 5 minutes later.